# The type 'IdentityRole' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to inherit my dbcontext in an asp.net core 2.0 library from IdentityDbContext:

Error   CS0012  The type 'IdentityRole' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

When I attempt to install the pkg I get:

Unable to find version '2.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores -Version 2.0.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

I've been going round and round with this for two days.  Hopefully a solution will come soon...

Answer (score 3):

Because I had the same problem: Add the nuget package via Package Manager Console to your project.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores -Version 2.0.2
```

And choose the correct nuget package version.

Answer (score 0):

Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Store will resolve the problem.